# how to filter a wijmo flex grid value

Tags: wijmo

**fruits**

---

Apple

Banana

Pear

Tomatoe

i have a flex grid that loads the above information

```
<wj-flex-grid   items-source="Module.Fruits " child-items-path="children" selection-mode="Row" allow-Sorting="false" is-read-only="true">
```

how do i filter the fruits column to leave out certain fruits i dont want for example with a select box this is what i would have done

```
 <select  ng-model="Model.Fruits" ng-options="fruit.FruitID as fruit.fruitName for fruit in Model.Fruits  | filter:{fruitName :'!pear'} | filter:{fruitName :'!apple'}>
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
```

and the above would leave out the values i specified.Now im not to sure how to do that with the flexgrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the same filter on CollectionView and then, bind it to FlexGrid. Here is the code:

```
$scope.cv.filter = function (item) {
         return item.name != "Washington";
     };
```

You can also check this fiddle implementing the same:http://jsfiddle.net/Lrdt7xv8/1/